# How to select/ check radio button based on the value from database?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, radio-button

I have radio button like below

```
 <dx:ASPxRadioButtonList ID="radClaimType" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="true" ValueType="System.String" Border-BorderStyle="None">
    <Items>
      <dx:ListEditItem Text="Expenses" Value="1" />
      <dx:ListEditItem Text="Travel" Value="2" />
    </Items>
</dx:ASPxRadioButtonList>
```

How do I select/check the radio button based on the value that I have inserted in database ?

Here is my code behind

```
Dim dt As New Datatable 
Dim strSelect As String = "SELECT claim_type FROM detail_table WHERE id = '30'"
Dim myconn As New clsConnection

Try
       myconn.OpenConnection()
       myconn.FillDataTable(dt, strSelect)
       myconn.CloseConnection()
    
       If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then  
         
           If dt.Rows(0).Item("claim_type") = 1 Then
             radClaimType.SelectedIndex = 1
           ElseIf dt.Rows(0).Item("claim_type") = 2 Then
             radClaimType.SelectedIndex = 2
           End If
      
          radClaimType.Enabled = False

       End If
Catch ex As Exception
 MsgBox("Error")
myconn.CloseConnection()
End Try
```

The result is like this which is incorrect because the claim_type value for id = '30' is 1 which is Expense. I have debug the code and the value for claim_type is indeed 1 but the radio button does not checked/selected to `Expense`. How do I correct this ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should tag what 3rd party control library you are using here.

Anyway, as a general rule, the asp.net RB-list can be set by "index", starting at 0, or you can set by value.

So, for your code, then this:

```
radClaimType.SelectedValue = dt.Rows(0).Item("claim_type")
```

You do NOT want to set by index, since the RB list could have ANY values, and

```
 0 = first one
 1 = 2nd one
 etc. etc. etc.
```

So, index starts at 0

but, you want to set the RB by "value", and hence:

```
radClaimType.SelectedValue = dt.Rows(0).Item("claim_type")
```

You can check your documentaton for that control (I don't have it).

But, you don't need a "if/then" here. You can set the value of the RB, and it should then select/display the value corectly

so with this:

```
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server"
            RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="true" >
            <asp:ListItem Value="100">Expenses</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="200">Travel</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Then I can set 0 (first) or 1 (second) using "indexing" like this:

```
RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 0    ' would select the 100
RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 1    ' would select the 200
```

Or, by value

```
RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue = 100   ' would select the first one
```

Comment: Thank you ! It works now. I was confused and don't know which one should I use.